# Sort multidimensional array with minimum loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How to sort following array with PHP based  on its `name`'s prefix number and produce the output as

```
    1-First
    2-Capico
    4-Apple
    10-Zebra



$array  = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 6 [name] => 1-First [slug] => aaa-a [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 6 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 4 [count] => 2 [cat_ID] => 6 [category_count] => 2 [category_description] => [cat_name] => 1-First [category_nicename] => aaa-a [category_parent] => 4 ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 9 [name] => 10-Zebra [slug] => aaa-f [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 9 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 4 [count] => 1 [cat_ID] => 9 [category_count] => 1 [category_description] => [cat_name] => 10-Zebra [category_nicename] => aaa-f [category_parent] => 4 ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 8 [name] => 2-Capico [slug] => aaa-c [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 8 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 4 [count] => 1 [cat_ID] => 8 [category_count] => 1 [category_description] => [cat_name] => 2-Capico [category_nicename] => aaa-c [category_parent] => 4 ) 
        [3] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 7 [name] => 4-Apple [slug] => aaa-b [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 7 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 4 [count] => 1 [cat_ID] => 7 [category_count] => 1 [category_description] => [cat_name] => 4-Apple [category_nicename] => aaa-b [category_parent] => 4 ) )
```

Tried using

```
sort($array,SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach ( $array as $single ) {
echo $single->name;
}
```

but display the output as

```
4-Apple
2-Capico
10-Zebra
1-First
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) 
    { 
        return strnatcasecmp($a->name, $b->name); 
    });`
```

Answer (score 3):

From PHP 5.3, you can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with an [anonymous function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). On older versions, you can use a normal compare function as illustrated in the manual.

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    //saving values converted to integer
    $intAname=(int) $a->name;
    $intBname=(int) $b->name;

    //if they are equal, do string comparison
    if ($intAname == $intBname) {
        return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
    }

    return ($intAname < $intBname) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Sort order will be fine because your `name` strings start with numbers, so PHP will [parse these variables as numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

**UPDATE:** Added integer casting as suggested by @binaryLV, and also solved the `1-foo and 1-bar` problem mentioned by @konforce (with `strcmp()`).

Comment: `"2-Capico"` > `"10-Zebra"`. I would add `(int)` before operands.

Comment: "*Sort order will be fine because (...)*" - did you try that? `var_dump('2-Capico' > '10-Zebra')` prints `boolean true`. If both strings would be numeric (rather than start with digits), then your statement would be true.

Comment: @stereofrog It won't give the right results. Now I see `strnatcasecmp()` used by @VolkerK, man, I did not know that one :).

Comment: @binaryLV Currently I cannot test it, but whenever I can, I will update.

Comment: That link to the manual describes how strings are converted to numbers, when such conversion is necessary. If both operands are strings and at least one of them is not numeric, then operands are not converted to numbers. To ilustrate that, `var_dump('2' == '0x2', '2' == '0x2x');` will output `true, false`, as in first case both strings are numeric, in second case second operand is not numeric.

Comment: @stereofrog Yes, exactly, @binaryLV already helped me on it. I will update my code.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, @konforce in comments of his answer noted that `1-foo` and `1-bar` will be considered equal, when sorting by numbers, so when `(int)$a->name == (int)$b->name` is true, then operands should be compared as strings.

Comment: @binaryLV, @stereofrog I have updated my answer, thanks for all your help. I will recheck everything when I can test my code.

Answer (score 3):

To sort numerically:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) { return $a->name - $b->name; });
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your response. let me try

Comment: @stereofrog, depends on the context. e.g., `1-foo` and `1-bar` will be considered equal when sorting by integers. But if the prefix index is unique, then it doesn't matter.